# Vue.js: get current `v-for` Objekt in @click-Method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a list with v-for over a couple of folders. when I click on one of these I want a function to execute.

My code looks like this:

```
<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="folder in folders">
      <a @click.prevent="expandFolder">{{ folder.name }}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  method: {
    expandFolder: function(e) {
      // How to access current folder here?
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Is there an easy way to access the current folder (without sub-components)?

(I'm also using Vuex but since this is a UI only operation without modification to data, I assume good practice to avoid Vuex actions, right?)

Answer (score 1):

If course the most obvious solutions it what I didn't think of in the beginning (arrrgghh):

```
<li v-for="folder in folders">
  <a @click.prevent="expandFolder(folder)">{{ folder.name }}</a>
  <!-- or even a property -->
  <a @click.prevent="expandFolder(folder.name)">{{ folder.name }}</a>
</li>
```